# Are weapons and armor made of Mithral or Adamantine considered magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, armor, special-materials

In a recent dungeon crawl, I was ambushed by some grey ooze. The ooze managed to land a couple successful hits on me, which would normally cause my armor to degrade. However, I was using a set of mithral chain mail that I had found in a previous session. I know that the statistics for mithral and adamant items are found in the DMG, which leads me to believe they are magical, but their descriptions don't really imply that they are magical.

Is the mithral armor considered magical for the purpose of resisting effects like degrading from the ooze? I also know that adamant armor and weapons exist in our game. Would they follow the same ruling as mithral?

Comment: The question might better be asked "In what way are Mithral or Adamantine magical?"  Based on the scant references in the books, this may not have a hard rule and require rulings ... the text of the question is well asked.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## There are magic and non-magic items made from adamantine

While the DMG lists **Adamantine Armor** as a magic item, some items made from adamantine are not magic.

Gargoyles resist damage from “nonmagical weapons that aren’t adamantine” (MM, p 140). It follows there would be nonmagical weapons that *are* adamantine.

So, adamantine weapons would strike gargoyles similarly to how magic weapons would, without being *magic weapons*, or even *magic items.*  Mechanically, they are similar to *silvered* weapons (the phrasing in monsters’ *resistances* blocks are the same) but they defeat a different set of monsters’ damage resistances.

#### Xanathar’s Guide does not call Adamantium “Magical”

*Xanathar’s Guide to Everything*  (p. 78) has a section on adamantium weapons which describes adamatine as “an ultrahard metal found in meteorites and extraordinary mineral veins” but does not mention it being magical.

*Xanathar’s* lists the properties of weapons “made from or coated by” adamantine. These are distinct from the proprties of magic items. For example, adamantine weapons don’t get *magic item resiliency*.

### Official Example (Spoiler Alert)

There is an example of such a weapon in official Wizard’s 5e material.

> In *The Lost Mine of Phandelver,* the **Spider Staff** is a “black, adamantine staff” that “can be wielded as a quarterstaff.”

Note, the staff does not strike as a “magic quarterstaff” like the **Staff of Power** does. It is a magic *item* but not a magic *weapon*. As far as whomping things goes, it is a “nonmagical weapon made of adamantine.”

#### For mithral items, the rules say very little

I’m not aware of any mention of mithral in the core rules outside of the magic armor. A DM might follow the example of adamantine — that it’s a rare metal that is often found in magic items. Or they might rule it is inherently magical.

#### Magic Items are defined as such. Custom items are defined by your DM.

If an item is listed as a *magic item* then in general they would have the qualities common to magic items of their type. A custom item invented by your DM might have any properties.

The particular qualities of any particular item in your game are of course up your DM. Your character might (and probably should) learn whether an item is magical or not, and its properties, resistances, etc., by means such as an *Identify* spell.

Comment: It follows that adamantine (weapon) has a particular property that behaves the same as magical versus a gargoyle.  It isn't unreasonable to conclude that adamantine is thus inherently magical, or, that it's magical character is restricted to a specific cases, like a gargoyle's skin.  You raise an interesting point in the answer ... that may only be solved by a ruling.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Not everything has to have a magic reason behind it, yeah? Couldn't they just be allergic to the metal? ;) Same verbiage is found on Golems though and we can probably agree they don't have allergies.

Comment: @Slagmoth I agree with your point, in that the whole issue might be directly related to hardness (at the mechanical/simulationist level) but as that's never spelled out, magical is one way to resolve that ambiguity.

Comment: @LordHieros, thanks, and yikes, that SA makes a muddle of things. DMG has staves that can be wielded “as a quarterstaff” and those that strike “as a magic quarterstaff”— but the post seems to say they all are magic weapons, regardless of the wording in the DMG. Maybe I'll have to remove that passage — but the Xanathar guidance is pretty clear.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Magical in D&D terms isn't the same as magical in common language. We'd generally consider a zombie an inherently magical creature, because you clearly need magic to make a corpse get up and start punching people, and yet a zombie functions just fine in an anti-magic zone, which is designed to block magical effects.

Comment: @EttinaKitten Or maybe it shouldn't?  (Unfortunately, there are a variety of ways for a zombie to exist, such as a wraith kills someone, other than the spells used by Clerics, wizards, etc).  Maybe the anti magic field should collapse a zombie. (But I suppose that's a separate question)

Comment: Jeremy Crawford tweeted an answer to this later in 2017:

"Mithral armor is a magic item. It follows the rules for such items, including the text in antimagic field on magic items."

https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/928368184075231232?lang=en

This suggests that armor made of mithral is not magical, but also not light or silent, but the mithral armor listed in the DMG is magical and both.

Answer (score 3):

Mithral and Adamantine armor appear under the "Magic Items" header of the DMG, and are listed in the magic item tables (Adamantine armor is actually the very first entry on pg. 150). This means that they are magic items, with all the attendant properties.

I don't think there's any listing for adamantine weapons anywhere in the handbooks. Given that the armors made from those materials are magic, it's not a stretch to say that the corresponding weapons are also magic.

Lore-wise, this can be justified by saying that adamantine and mithral are inherently magical materials.

Comment: I think that the title and the body ask different questions but DMG p246 touches on Adamantine and Mithril being materials like wood and iron. So I guess would an adamantine paper clip be magical?

Comment: I agree, and I tried to answer the question in the body. As for the paperclip, it is a bit ambiguous, as Adamantine was explicitly nonmagical in 3.5e, and I'd bet that the designers put the armor under magic items just to streamline things a bit.

Comment: agreed on the streamlining, their misuse of several words in the rules make be cringe at times, and I tend to rule that they meant it as part of the Treasure super-heading over the Magical Item sub-heading as it is a rare and wonderful item.

Comment: What you found there was not armor made out of adamantine though, it was Adamantine Armor, a specific magic item